# Have a single query in greenDAO ignore the session cache

Tags: android, greendao

I currently track individual changes to certain objects in my app. This already works fine by comparing the current object (a copy that was modified by the user) with what's in the database.

```
public void syncChanges(GsonTask current, GsonTask old) {
    // Load previous version of object if not provided.
    if (old == null) {
        // Here I get the old object from the database, while the user modified one is not touched.
        old = TasksService.getInstance().loadTask(current.getId());
    }

    // Bunch of logic to compare the current and old objects and track changes...

    // Another bunch of logic to sync the changes found to the server.

    // Save the current state of the object to the database (replacing the old one).
    TasksService.getInstance().saveTask(current);
}
```

But this approach introduces performance issues, as I need to copy the objects I get from greenDAO in order to be able to compare them later. So, in essence, I'm not using the session cache to my advantage, as new objects (the copies) are always created after queries.

```
public List<GsonTask> loadAllTasks() {
    // Load data from greenDAO and create the user modifiable copies.
    return gsonFromTasks(mExtTaskDao.listAllTasks());
}

private List<GsonTask> gsonFromTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    List<GsonTask> gsonTasks = new ArrayList<GsonTask>();
    if (tasks != null) {
        // Create the copies.
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            gsonTasks.add(new GsonTask(...));
        }
    }
    return gsonTasks;
}
```

To fix this performance bottleneck, I'm now using the objects returned by greenDAO directly, without creating copies. This makes list loading much faster, but now I can no longer track changes. When I try to compare the current object with the one in the database, my query returns the already modified object (as expected with the session cache).

```
public List<Task> loadAllTasks() {
    List<Task> tasks = mExtTaskDao.listAllTasks();

    // Return the greenDAO objects directly, without creating copies.
    return tasks != null ? tasks : new ArrayList<Task>();
}

public void syncChanges(GsonTask current, GsonTask old) {
    if (old == null) {
         // Here I can no longer load the previous state of this object (i.e. what's actually persisted in the database).
         // old is now just a reference to current.
         old = TasksService.getInstance().loadTask(current.getId());
    }

    // Comparison between the user modified object and what's in the database can't happen, as both objects are the same. 

    // I get sad. :/ Syncing changes is no longer possible.

    // Saving the current state of the object still works, as expected.
    TasksService.getInstance().saveTask(current);
}
```

I don't want to disable the session cache because the performance increase is significant. I also wouldn't like to clear it with `daoSession.clear()`, as the code above runs very often and the cache would have to be rebuilt all the time, invalidating the performance improvements.

So, is there a way to ignore the session cache for a single query only? Or somehow ask for a new object instead of the existing reference?

```
public Task selectTask(Long id) {
    // Here I'd like to receive a new object, not the existing reference.
    return mDao.queryBuilder().where(TaskDao.Properties.Id.eq(id)).unique();
}
```

When I query the object from the database to compare with its user modified state, I would like to be able to receive a new object exactly as it's persisted in the database, and not a reference to what was loaded before. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Apparently I'm not allowed to duplicate my answer here, but see my answer on this stackoverflow.com/a/47401143/2775083 post regarding why this behaviour is occuring